# Get records from the last 30 days using timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a events table and each event has a date, the date that is stored in the table is a php time() stamp. I need to list the events but I only want to list the events from the last 30 days.

This is the current SQL query I have

```
SELECT event_id, event_name, event_date
FROM events
where e.event_date <= 'time()'
ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT event_id, event_name, event_date
FROM events
where FROM_UNIXTIME(event_date) >= curdate() - interval 30 day
ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

Comment: Think your query is missing an AS in there.

Comment: Your answer does not work correctly, the `event_date` is a unix timestamp not a "m/d/Y or m-d-Y" date format.

Comment: Updated the answer. Use FROM_UNIXTIME